# Apllying arguments in javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to make a small utility function `toPromise` that transforms a function using callback into a promise function (using Q).
Here is the utility:

```
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "toPromise", {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: function(self) {
    var $this;
    $this = this;
    return function() {
      var args, deferred;
      deferred = Q.defer();
      args = arguments;
      args[args.length] = deferred.resolve;
      console.dir(args);
      $this.apply(self, args);
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  }
});
```

Here is the usage:

```
var f = function(nickname, name, callback){
  console.log(arguments)
  callback(undefined, name+" "+nickname);
};
f.toPromise(this)("a", "b").then(function(str){
  console.log(str)
});
```

But the output is:

```
{ '0': 'a', '1': 'b', '2': [Function] } // This is debugging from utils
{ '0': 'a', '1': 'b' } // and from the function f

C:\test.js:4
  callback(undefined, name+" "+nickname);
  ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So why is the third arg (in utils), the function, not passed in the `apply` ?

Comment: Random guess: convert `arguments` to an array before assigning to `args`

Comment: @Kos thanks! It worked. Post an answer please...

Comment: Please don't define properties on the object prototype. To transform a function into a Promise all you need to do is call `nfbind` on it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: +1 for `nfbind`, but notice that he doesn't use `Object.prototype`

Comment: Oh yeah, it's the function prototype, not sure if that's better or worse :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arguments` object is not a real array:

```
>>> function getArguments() { return arguments; }
>>> var a = getArguments(1,2,3), b = [1,2,3];
>>> a[3] = 4; b[3] = 4;
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a.length
3
>>> b.length
4
```

so if you intend to modify it or pass it around to outside the function it's good to convert it to a real array:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Comment: Note, if actually promisifying, what OP is doing is a really slow way to do it, and calling `.slice.call(arguments)` is also much slower than the alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You did assign the callback to the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), but since it's not an actual array that did not automatically increase its `length` property. With `length` still being `2`, your callback was simply skipped in the `apply`.

The fix is simple:

```
Function.prototype.toPromise = function(self) {
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
        var deferred = Q.defer();
        arguments[arguments.length++] = deferred.resolve;
//                                ^^
        fn.apply(self||this, arguments);
        return deferred.promise;
    };
};
```

You also might use `Array.prototype.push.call(arguments, deferred.resolve)`. Notice that [`Q` already provides <s>such</s> similar<sup>1</sup> a functionality](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#interfacing-with-nodejs-callbacks) (with probably optimized efficiency), so if you just want to use it on the prototype you'd better do

```
Function.prototype.toPromise = function(self) {
    return Q.nbind(this, self);
};
```

<sub>1: Notice that `resolve()` does not take an error argument, like "nodebacks" usually do</sub>

Comment: I had no idea push.call works on `arguments`. Although note, OP is promisifying something that looks isn't really a nodeback.

Comment: Well, [`push`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.7) is one of these "intentionally generic" Array methods, and explicitly increases the `length` property :-) You're right with nodeback/callback, though OP's use of `callback(undefined, name+" "+nickname);` tricked me into that :-) Not sure he really wants to pass `def.resolve`, or rather `def.makeNodeResolver()`.